# GTK Dark themes on QT applications?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gtk, qt

I'm using Arch Linux with Xfce desktop environment. I want to apply Plata GTK ***DARK*** theme for QT apps. I've changed `/etc/profile`, but I've some bugs with themes. Menu called by right-click is with white background and white text. Toolbars are white, too.

- Toolbar bug:

[image]

- Right-click bug:

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: Is Qt able to load GTK themes by itself, or do you use a plugin for this?

Comment: I've used qt5ct and styleplugins. Now I'm using only styleplugins and I've activated gtk2 theme with changing file `/etc/profile`